# Magento 2 Help - Sub-Categories not working on mouse over

Tags: category, menu, submenu

Just getting the hang of magento 2, having a slight problem which I need your help on.

Using Magento 2.0.12
Using the basic luma theme

The sub-categories on the nav menu on front end were appearing on mouse-over, however after installing the free megastore banner slider and implementing 2 sliders (above menu and below menu with slides) - the dropdown menu sub categories on mouse over stopped working.

anyone got any clue?

The main category shows in the menu "products'
However, every sub-category doesn't show on mouse over.

I have made sure Include in Navigation Menu is set to YES on all of them

They are set under default category in the backend 
- default category > products > boost pedals

Only 'products' show on the menu front end.

I have also tried running the following command and refreshing cache.

php bin/magento indexer:reindex